# How to reference the value of an environment variable with using another environment variable value in variable name?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I know that similar questions have been asked before and I have seen them but neither does `!var[%Z%]!` nor `%var[!Z!]%` work here:

```
@echo off
set Z=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (Data) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set var[!count!]=%%x
)
:end
cls 
echo %var[!Z!]%
choice  /N /C QE
IF %errorlevel% == 1 GOTO ZP
IF %errorlevel% == 2 GOTO ZM
pause >nul
goto :end

:ZP
set /a Z=%Z%+1
goto :end
:ZM
set /a Z=%Z%-1
goto :end
```

I tried them and they don't work. What can I do?

`Data` is a file with following lines:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
AA
AB
AC
AD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this was your intention, *(small modifications included)*. i.e. to be able to two way cycle through the data items using the <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> keys.

*Code as per the suggestion in my comment:*

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set /A "Z=count=0"

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Tokens=* UseBackQ" %%G In ("Data.ext") Do (
    Set /A count += 1
    Set "var[!count!]=%%G"
)
Set "count="

:End
ClS 
Echo(!var[%Z%]!
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C QE /N
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo ZM
GoTo ZP
Pause 1>NUL
GoTo End

:ZP
Set /A Z += 1
GoTo End

:ZM
Set /A Z -= 1
GoTo End
```

Comment: well maybe it does not work on windows 11
data does not have lines containing those but contains *, 7, S and E, 0s... alot, + and X

Comment: I didn't change  the `echo`ing of variables containing `0` or less, _(or in fact more  than the final value of `%count%` immediately after he `for` loop)_, other than to include `(` to prevent `echo is ON` messages should the `E` or `Q` keys extend the sequence too far in one direction. I could have done so, but my intention was not to change the OP's code so much that they were no longer able to modify their 'real' code without breaking something. The only purpose of what I've posted was to show that `Echo(!var[%Z%]!` works, the rest of the code is really irrelevant.

Comment: It does work @Improster8, you are wrong!

Comment: Perhaps an issue is the wrong start value of `Z`, which should be `1` since the (pseudo-)array indexing is not zero-based. I might also be a good idea to limit `Z` in the loop to not exceed the indexing range…

Comment: Yes it initially `echo`es nothing, and if the end user continues to enter `E`, it will continue to echo nothing. It will only start to provide output when sufficient `Q`'s have been input. I would certainly make significant changes, if it were mine, but those would still use `Echo(!var[%Z%]!` which is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: I did a little bogus with the code a minute ago. it matches the original but it works now